# Image of finite locally free morphism is open

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f$ be a finite and locally free morphism $\phi :X \longrightarrow S$.
In Szamuely (Galois groups and fundamental groups), it is said that the image of $\phi$ is open.
The proof of Szamuely goes as follow. It is open because by local freeness $\phi_* \mathcal{O}_X$ has nonzero stalks over an open subset of $S$.

Why does there exists such an open subset of $S$ ?
How it implies that the image of $\phi$ is open ?

Comment: "Locally free" implies "flat" (because "flat" is local and free modules are flat).  Flat morphisms (of finite presentation) are universally open: EGA IV₂, theorem 2.4.6.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thank you for your answer. But I try to understand the proof of Szamuely.

Comment: There are a lot of parts to put together here but none of them are hard, I don't think. To start: in general (forget the hypotheses for the moment) $\phi_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is going to have nonzero stalks at points in the image of $\phi$. Do you see why?

Comment: @hoot Yes. If $\sigma_{f(x)} = 0$ (where $\sigma$ is a section of $\phi_*\mathcal{O}_X$), then $\sigma = 0$ over an open subset $V \subset S$ with $f(x) \in V$ which implies that $\sigma = 0$ over $\phi^{-1}V$, so $\sigma_x = 0$. It is impossible since $X$ is a scheme.

Comment: I think you might need to say more. I think basically what you're getting toward is that there's a map $(\phi_*\mathcal{O}_X)_{f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Certainly it takes $0$ to $0$. Why does the morphism have to be nonzero?

Comment: @hoot It is because the map is surjective. Isn't it ?

Comment: I don't think it has to be surjective.

Comment: @hoot Thank you. I will think about this.

Comment: Once you have that, two more things: (a) In general one can have $(\phi_*\mathcal{O}_X)_s \neq 0$ for $s$ not in the image of $f$. But this can't happen if the image of $f$ is closed. (b) Just by the definition of local freeness, if a locally free sheaf $E$ has nonzero stalk at a point then it has nonzero stalks in a neighborhood of that point.

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't claim to answer the question (that's why I posted a comment, not an answer), just put the result in context.

Comment: Also, you should have stated in the question that Szamuely first points out that the image of $\phi$ is closed (because $\phi$ is finite, hence proper).